# How does CircleCI achieve "merged" Docker cgroup namespaces?

Tags: linux, docker, circleci, cgroups

I was trying to debug a failed test job in a CircleCI workflow which had a config similar to this:

```
  integration_tests:
    docker:
      - image: my-group/our-custom-image:latest
      - image: postgres:9.6.11
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: db
    steps:
      - stuff && things
```

When I [ran the job with SSH debugging](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ssh-access-jobs/) and SSH'ed to where the CircleCI app told me, I found myself in a strange maze of twisty little namespaces, all alike. I ran `ps awx` and *I could see processes from both the two docker containers:*

```
root@90c93bcdd369:~# ps awwwx
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 pts/0    Ss     0:00 /dev/init -- /bin/sh
    6 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/sh
    7 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 postgres
   40 ?        Ssl    0:02 /bin/circleci-agent ...
  105 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process  
  106 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process  
  107 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process  
  108 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process  
  109 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process  
  153 pts/1    Ss+    0:00 bash "stuff && things"
  257 pts/1    Sl+    0:31 /path/to/our/application
  359 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
  369 pts/2    R+     0:00 ps awwwx
```

It seems like what they did was somehow "merged" the cgroup namespaces of the two docker containers into a *third* namespace, under which the shell they provided me resides. Because pid 7 is running from one docker container, and pid 257 is the application running inside the `my-group/our-custom-image:latest` container.

The cgroup view from `/proc` shows some kind of merged cgroups going on, it looks like?

```
root@90c93bcdd369:~# cat /proc/7/cgroup 
12:devices:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
11:blkio:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
10:memory:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
9:hugetlb:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
8:perf_event:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
7:net_cls,net_prio:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
6:rdma:/
5:cpu,cpuacct:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
4:cpuset:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
3:pids:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
2:freezer:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
1:name=systemd:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/d8fc5294708fd4cf91fa405d6462571e1dc56413b55a6b6e5790b8f158fee632
0::/system.slice/containerd.service
root@90c93bcdd369:~# cat /proc/257/cgroup 
12:devices:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
11:blkio:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
10:memory:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
9:hugetlb:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
8:perf_event:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
7:net_cls,net_prio:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
6:rdma:/
5:cpu,cpuacct:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
4:cpuset:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
3:pids:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
2:freezer:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
1:name=systemd:/docker/94376e7880579c6bde0622017594fcdb8d5767788bb4790c0f014db282198577/90c93bcdd3693a918adddf62939c5b31e86868864edabe7347a268149e797f43
0::/system.slice/containerd.service
```

Is there a standard Docker feature, or some cgroup feature being used to produce this magic? Or is this some custom, proprietary CircleCI feature?